# API Exception (OAuthException: Cannot call API on behalf of this user)

Tags: api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Got the following exception when calling api (/me) using the latest PHP SDK.

OAuthException: Cannot call API on behalf of this user.

The same exception appears for some facebook account only. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I found the source of the problem (on our site, at least).  In Facebook's developer console (https://developers.facebook.com/apps), our app was showing an invalid privacy policy.  Due to this, Facebook had automatically placed our app into Sandbox Mode.

**Updating our privacy policy and (more notably) removing our app from Sandbox Mode caused this error to cease.**

Other users seem to have had some success with removing regional (country-specific) restrictions on who can and cannot log in to their app (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-social-auth/XaE5dFXEqhA)

Additionally, @Igy's questions sound reasonable and might lead to finding a solution as well.

Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that user's access token still valid? Has the user blocked you? Can you navigate to the user's profile manually? (i.e their profile might be unavailable)